# Tensor shape modification using slicing and None

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am bit puzzled by how to read and understand a simple line of code:

- I have a tensor `input` of shape `(19,4,64,64,3)`.
- The line of code `input[:, None]` returns a tensor of shape `(19, 1,
  4, 64, 64, 3)`.

How should I understand the behavior of that line? It seems that `None` is adding a dimension, with a size of 1. But why is this added on that specific position (between 19 and 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `None` adds a new dimension. You can also use `tf.newaxis` for this which is a bit more explicit IMHO.

The new dimension is added in axis 1 because that's where it appears in the index. E.g. `input[:, :, None]` should result in shape (19, 4, 1, 64, 64, 3) and so on.
It might get clearer if we write all the dimensions in the slicing: `input[:, None, :, :, :, :]`. In slicing, `:` simply means taking all elements of the dimension. So by using one `:`, we take all elements of dimension 0 and then "move on" to dimension 1. Since `None` appears here, we know that the new size-1 axis should be in dimension 1. Accordingly, the remaining dimensions get "pushed back".

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. Much clearer now.